# Postgres composite PK where one component is sequence different for each value of other field

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, sequence

Let's say I have a `a_table` with following fields:

- id_a: bigint
- id_b: int
- some_third_value: text

I'd like to create a composite primary key on `id_a` and `id_b` so that `id_a` would be a sequence, but it would be a different sequence depending on the value of `id_b` and this all would work automatically with inserts. So lets say I would insert:

```
insert into a_table (id_b, some_third_value) values (1, 'Hello');
insert into a_table (id_b, some_third_value) values (1, 'World');
insert into a_table (id_b, some_third_value) values (2, 'Me here!');
```

Then the resulting rows would be:

```
id_a|id_b|some_third_value
1   |1   |Hello
2   |1   |World
1   |2   |Me here!
```

And every time I'd insert a new row with a new `id_b` which is not present before, it would create a new sequence for this new `id_b`'s `id_a`.

Can this be done? And if it can be done then is it a bad idea if let's say I had few million rows in that table and few hundred different `id_b`'s?

Comment: Why do you need this? I'm asking because this sounds like an X-Y Problem™.

Comment: @mustaccio Maybe. Very simply put: I want to reflect id_a to external API. id_b represents a user who queries the API. I don't want user to know how many records in total are in db. But I do want users own records to be in order by ID's.

Comment: Just use a normal sequence value for the primary key. The sequence will have gaps anyway, so it doesn't matter if the gaps are bigger or smaller. What you want is difficult and will perform badly.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's answer enough for me. Was just wondering if perhaps that's an OK practice, but I guess not.